# How to create a new branch from another repository?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-repo

I have a repository (*repo1*) with a master branch and another repository (*repo2*) with a master branch. Now I want to create a new branch in *repo1* from *repo2* with all commits history.

---

My expected result:

```
repo2
----
|
 \
  master


repo1
----------
|         |
 \         \
  master    master-from-repo2
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
cd repo1
git fetch repo2 master:master-from-repo2
```

Remote branch `master` is fetched from `repo2` into local branch `master-from-repo2`.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. If repo2 has another branch and when I want to get this branch can I do it: `any-branch-in-repo2:master-from-repo2` instead of `master:master-from-repo2`?

Comment: Yes, any branch will do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if the `repo2` that I want to fetch is local?

Comment: @bytrangle Shouldn't matter, `git fetch` fetches over any supported protocol, git://, ssh://, https://, file:/// (local). Just add `repo2` as a remote: `git remote add repo2 file:///path/to/local/repo`

Comment: @phd Thank you. Just fetched a local repo successfully.